# How to check for Firebase permission denied?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How do I check for "permission_denied" in my swift code?! so that I can display a proper alert to user?

```
    self.ref = Database.database().reference(withPath: "PlayerBoxes")
    //
    handle = ref.child(pID).observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
        // Do Something
    }) { (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }



    // Update info into Firebase, do not overwrite entire node
    ref.child(self.pID).updateChildValues(sqr.toDictionary())  <-- Permission Denied
```

Comment: Please accept my response as an answer since it resolves your question and for your question to be closed. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`updateChildValues(withCompletionBlock:)`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/FIRDatabaseReference#/c:objc(cs)FIRDatabaseReference(im)updateChildValues:withCompletionBlock:) instead.

This returns a database reference along with any raised error.

```
ref.child(self.pID).updateChildValues(sqr.toDictionary()) { (error, reference) in
    if error != nil
    {
        // handle the error
        print(error!.localizedDescription)
    }

    // you're fine, no error raised
}
```